# VS 2010 SP1 installation failed for VS 2010 Ultimate trial

Tags: visual-studio-2010, service-pack

When i try to install VS 2010 SP1 for VS 2010 Ultimate(trial version)
I get this error
**"Installation did not succees"**
**Fatal error during installation**

Log file is displayed below :

Number of applicable items: 16
Summary Information:

```
SetupUtility
Service Pack 1 Package
Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2010 Object Model - ENU
Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Performance Collection Tools - ENU
Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate - ENU
Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 ADO.NET Entity Framework Tools
Dotfuscator Software Services - Community Edition
Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Transact-SQL Language Service
Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Management Objects
Microsoft SQL Server System CLR Types
Microsoft F# Redist 2.0
VSTO 4.0 Runtime x86
Help Viewer v1.1
Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 x86 Runtime - 10.0.40219
Microsoft Visual C++ Compilers 2010 Standard x86 - 10.0.40219
NDP40-KB2468871.exe


D:\VS2010SP1\Dotfuscator\DotfuscatorCE_5.0.2500.msi - Signature verification for file Dotfuscator\DotfuscatorCE_5.0.2500.msi (D:\VS2010SP1\Dotfuscator\DotfuscatorCE_5.0.2500.msi) failed with error 0x80090327 (An unknown error occurred while processing the certificate.)
Starting install of item 'VS10sp1-KB983509' at tickCount = 182655609
Exe (D:\VS2010SP1\SetupUtility.exe) succeeded.
Exe Log File: dd_SetupUtility.txt
MSI (D:\VS2010SP1\VS10sp1_x86.msi) Installation succeeded. Msi Log: Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Service Pack 1_20130225_121918559-MSI_VS10sp1_x86.msi.txt
Patch (D:\VS2010SP1\VS10sp1-KB983509.msp;D:\VS2010SP1\VC10sp1-KB983509-x86.msp;D:\VS2010SP1\VC10sp1-KB983509-x64.msp;D:\VS2010SP1\VC10sp1-KB983509-IA64.msp;D:\VS2010SP1\VS10sp1-KB983509-Pro.msp) Install succeeded on product (Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2010 Object Model - ENU). Msi Log:
Patch (D:\VS2010SP1\VS10sp1-KB983509.msp;D:\VS2010SP1\VC10sp1-KB983509-x86.msp;D:\VS2010SP1\VC10sp1-KB983509-x64.msp;D:\VS2010SP1\VC10sp1-KB983509-IA64.msp;D:\VS2010SP1\VS10sp1-KB983509-Pro.msp) Install succeeded on product (Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Performance Collection Tools SP1 - ENU). Msi Log:
Patch (D:\VS2010SP1\VS10sp1-KB983509.msp;D:\VS2010SP1\VC10sp1-KB983509-x86.msp;D:\VS2010SP1\VC10sp1-KB983509-x64.msp;D:\VS2010SP1\VC10sp1-KB983509-IA64.msp;D:\VS2010SP1\VS10sp1-KB983509-Pro.msp) Install failed on product (Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate - ENU). Msi Log:
Exe (D:\VS2010SP1\SetupUtility.exe) succeeded.
Exe Log File: dd_SetupUtility.txt
Patch (D:\VS2010SP1\VS10sp1-KB983509.msp;D:\VS2010SP1\VC10sp1-KB983509-x86.msp;D:\VS2010SP1\VC10sp1-KB983509-x64.msp;D:\VS2010SP1\VC10sp1-KB983509-IA64.msp;D:\VS2010SP1\VS10sp1-KB983509-Pro.msp) Install succeeded on product (Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2010 Object Model - ENU). Msi Log:
Patch (D:\VS2010SP1\VS10sp1-KB983509.msp;D:\VS2010SP1\VC10sp1-KB983509-x86.msp;D:\VS2010SP1\VC10sp1-KB983509-x64.msp;D:\VS2010SP1\VC10sp1-KB983509-IA64.msp;D:\VS2010SP1\VS10sp1-KB983509-Pro.msp) Install succeeded on product (Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Performance Collection Tools SP1 - ENU). Msi Log:
Patch (D:\VS2010SP1\VS10sp1-KB983509.msp;D:\VS2010SP1\VC10sp1-KB983509-x86.msp;D:\VS2010SP1\VC10sp1-KB983509-x64.msp;D:\VS2010SP1\VC10sp1-KB983509-IA64.msp;D:\VS2010SP1\VS10sp1-KB983509-Pro.msp) Install failed on product (Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate - ENU). Msi Log:
MSI (D:\VS2010SP1\VS10sp1_x86.msi) Uninstall succeeded. Msi Log: Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Service Pack 1_20130225_121918559-MSI_VS10sp1_x86.msi.txt
Final Result: Installation failed with error code: (0x80070643), "Fatal error during installation. " (Elapsed time: 0 00:55:28).
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you not already using ISO version of SP1, you should try it. See also this thread for [possible solutions](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vssetup/thread/57de87cb-607f-4c49-baa3-128eb0fbebfd/).

I would also recommend to try a complete reinstallation (uninstall VS2010, then istall, and then try to apply SP1).

Comment: Not working.any of these solution

Comment: @ravidev - Load up a Virtual Machine and verify the problem exists in a clean installation of Windows.

Comment: I did follow steps. 1) Uninstall VS 2010 Ultimate 2) Reinstall it 3) Install VS 2010 SP1 ..problem solved